# Print all element in XML extractor in U-Sql

Tags: xml, extract, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am new to U-Sql and writing code for extracting xml element. Here is my XML code.

```
<Dispositions>
  <Disposition>test 1</Disposition>
  <Disposition> test 2</Disposition> 
</Dispositions>
```

I was trying to display all "Disposition" values. But final output displaying "Test 2" only.
I have code as below.

```
DECLARE @testFile string ="Marlboro20180301000000_child.xml";     
@xmlElementRowPath= EXTRACT Disposition string
    FROM @testFile
         USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml.XmlExtractor("Dispositions",
         new SQL.MAP<string,string>{
{"Disposition","Disposition"} 
} 
);

@words =
        SELECT Ar.word, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM @xmlElementRowPath
        CROSS APPLY
            EXPLODE(new SQL.ARRAY<String>( Disposition.Split(','))) AS Ar(word)
    GROUP BY Ar.word;
    //ORDER BY count DESC;
OUTPUT @words
TO "test.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

I have been expecting output as

```
Test 1
Test 2
```

But receiving only `Test 2` as output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work using the `XmlDomExtractor`.  Some sample code:

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];

// Get the xml using sample extractor
@input = EXTRACT Disposition string
     FROM "/input/yourXML.xml"
     USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml.XmlDomExtractor(rowPath:"Disposition",
                             columnPaths:new SQL.MAP<string, string> { {".", "Disposition"} } );


// Do some processing here
@output = SELECT * FROM @input;


// Output
OUTPUT @output
TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

My results:

[image: My results]

I'm not sure why you need the `Split` method - does the xml `Disposition` node hold text that needs to be split by some delimiter?  If so, please post some more realistic sample data.

Comment: Thanks. Its worked. I am totally new to U-Sql and doing some POC based on google. I made myself code make complex.